# Media query is not working in simple site layout

Tags: html, css

I am trying to copy a w3schools sample layout. They used `float` for content column but I think `flex` will be more flexing here. Everything is pretty okey except media query. When I apply media query to set the width of `.left` & `.right` column, it don't work. Most probably they grow 100% width within their own but they don't actually expand in whole page...

I tried to remove flex with `display: block;` but it didn't work. What can I do now?

JS Bin Link for w3schools: https://jsbin.com/befabibewi/edit?html,css,output 
JS Bin Link for my layout: https://jsbin.com/hobilaquyo/edit?html,css,output

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

html {
  font-family: verdana, san-serif; 
  background: #f1f1f1; 
}

header {
  background: white; 
  width: 100%; 
  padding: 60px; 
  text-align: center; 
}


/* Navigation Menu Started */
.nav {
  overflow: hidden; 
  background: #1c1c1c; 
}

.nav a {
  float: left;  
  color: white; 
  padding: 12px; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  text-align: center; 
}

.nav a:hover {
  color: black; 
  background: white; 
}

.nav-out {
  float: right !important; 
}
/* Navigation Menu Ended */


main {
  display: flex; 
}

.left {
  width: 70%; 
  padding: 10px; 
}

.right {
  width: 30%; 
  padding: 10px; 
}


/* post archive as card */
.card {
  background: white; 
  padding: 20px; 
  margin-top: 20px; 
  overflow: auto; 
}

/* button for post archive */ 
button {
  padding: 8px; 
  border: 1px solid #555; 
  float: right; 
  cursor: pointer; 
}

/* creating a fake image preview */
.img {
  background: #ccc; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 150px; 
  padding: 16px; 
}

.about-me {
  background: white; 
  padding: 20px; 
  margin-top: 20px; 

}

/* round image for about me section */
.round-img {
  background: #ccc; 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px; 
  padding: 16px; 
  border-radius: 50px;  
}

/* related news styling */
.related-news {
  background: white; 
  padding: 20px; 
  margin-top: 20px; 
}

.related-news-thumbnail {
  background: #ccc; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 80px; 
  padding: 16px;   
}

/* follow me section */
.follow-me {
  background: white; 
  padding: 20px; 
  margin-top: 20px; 
}

/* Our symantec footer */
footer {
  background: #c9c9c9; 
  padding: 20px; 
  text-align: center; 
  margin-top: 12px; 
}


/* When screen is 600px or lower, every post archive card as well as sidebar will be presented as full width block.  */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .left, .right {
    display: block; 
    width: 100%;  
    background: red; /* background is currently for testing purpose, to see if media query is actually working or not. You see, this property is working, where width is not working */
  }


/* Simple Nav styling. */ 
  .nav a{
    display: block; 
    width: 100%; 
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Copying W3schools Sample Site</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Site header -->
<header>
  <h1>My Website </h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
</header>

<!-- Navigation menu -->
<div class="nav">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-out">Link 4</a>
</div><br>

<!-- main tag, post archive and sidebar goes here -->
<main>
  
<!-- post archive --> 
<div class="left">

<!-- every card is represented as a single post archive -->  <div class="card">
     <h2>Some title here for you</h2>
     <h6>Date - 02.04.2020</h6>
     <div class="img">Image</div>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore possimus assumenda tempore facilis <quam!lorem7></quam!lorem7></p>
     <button>Read More</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card">
     <h2>Some title here for you</h2>
     <h6>Date - 02.04.2020</h6>
     <div class="img">Image</div>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore possimus assumenda tempore facilis quam! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
     <button>Read More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  
  <div class="card">
     <h2>Some title here for you</h2>
     <h6>Date - 02.04.2020</h6>
     <div class="img">Image</div>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. ! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum fugit, praesentium dolores.</p>
     <button>Read More</button>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- sidebar panel -->
<div class="right">
  
  <!-- about me -->
  <div class="about-me">
    <div class="round-img"></div>
    <h3>Forhad Rahman</h3>
    <p>Hi, I am new in web designing, developing and learning. Code on! :)</p>
  </div>
  
  <!-- related news -->
  <div class="related-news">
    <h5>Here is some related news for you</h5>
    <div class="related-news-thumbnail"></div>
    
    <h5>Can you try these news right away?</h5>
    <div class="related-news-thumbnail"></div>

    <h5>Some hot news is waiting for you!</h5>
    <div class="related-news-thumbnail"></div>

    <h5>Fresh news are here! Check it out. </h5>
    <div class="related-news-thumbnail"></div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- follow me block -->
  <div class="follow-me">
    <h3>Follow Me</h3>
    <p>Some text...</p>
  </div>
</div>
</main>

<!-- This is footer, symantec footer! :D -->
<footer>
  <h2>Footer</h2>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The media query is working, but your main is still using `display:flex` which is still creating columns in the flex layout. You must remove flexbox layout and make it default block like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    /* REMOVE THE DISPLAY FLEX */
    main {
        display: block; 
    }
}
```

It works when you do this. You can see it working below.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

html {
  font-family: verdana, san-serif; 
  background: #f1f1f1; 
}

header {
  background: white; 
  width: 100%; 
  padding: 60px; 
  text-align: center; 
}


/* Navigation Menu Started */
.nav {
  overflow: hidden; 
  background: #1c1c1c; 
}

.nav a {
  float: left;  
  color: white; 
  padding: 12px; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  text-align: center; 
}

.nav a:hover {
  color: black; 
  background: white; 
}

.nav-out {
  float: right !important; 
}
/* Navigation Menu Ended */


main {
  display: flex; 
}

.left {
  width: 70%; 
  padding: 10px; 
}

.right {
  width: 30%; 
  padding: 10px; 
}


/* post archive as card */
.card {
  background: white; 
  padding: 20px; 
  margin-top: 20px; 
  overflow: auto; 
}

/* button for post archive */ 
button {
  padding: 8px; 
  border: 1px solid #555; 
  float: right; 
  cursor: pointer; 
}

/* creating a fake image preview */
.img {
  background: #ccc; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 150px; 
  padding: 16px; 
}

.about-me {
  background: white; 
  padding: 20px; 
  margin-top: 20px; 

}

/* round image for about me section */
.round-img {
  background: #ccc; 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px; 
  padding: 16px; 
  border-radius: 50px;  
}

/* related news styling */
.related-news {
  background: white; 
  padding: 20px; 
  margin-top: 20px; 
}

.related-news-thumbnail {
  background: #ccc; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 80px; 
  padding: 16px;   
}

/* follow me section */
.follow-me {
  background: white; 
  padding: 20px; 
  margin-top: 20px; 
}

/* Our symantec footer */
footer {
  background: #c9c9c9; 
  padding: 20px; 
  text-align: center; 
  margin-top: 12px; 
}


/* When screen is 600px or lower, every post archive card as well as sidebar will be presented as full width block.  */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .left, .right {
    display: block; 
    width: 100%;  
    background: red;
  }

 /* REMOVE THE DISPLAY FLEX */
  main {
    display: block; 
  }

/* Simple Nav styling. */ 
  .nav a{
    display: block; 
    width: 100%; 
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Copying W3schools Sample Site</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Site header -->
<header>
  <h1>My Website </h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
</header>

<!-- Navigation menu -->
<div class="nav">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-out">Link 4</a>
</div><br>

<!-- main tag, post archive and sidebar goes here -->
<main>
  
<!-- post archive --> 
<div class="left">

<!-- every card is represented as a single post archive -->  <div class="card">
     <h2>Some title here for you</h2>
     <h6>Date - 02.04.2020</h6>
     <div class="img">Image</div>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore possimus assumenda tempore facilis <quam!lorem7></quam!lorem7></p>
     <button>Read More</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card">
     <h2>Some title here for you</h2>
     <h6>Date - 02.04.2020</h6>
     <div class="img">Image</div>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore possimus assumenda tempore facilis quam! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
     <button>Read More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  
  <div class="card">
     <h2>Some title here for you</h2>
     <h6>Date - 02.04.2020</h6>
     <div class="img">Image</div>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. ! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum fugit, praesentium dolores.</p>
     <button>Read More</button>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- sidebar panel -->
<div class="right">
  
  <!-- about me -->
  <div class="about-me">
    <div class="round-img"></div>
    <h3>Forhad Rahman</h3>
    <p>Hi, I am new in web designing, developing and learning. Code on! :)</p>
  </div>
  
  <!-- related news -->
  <div class="related-news">
    <h5>Here is some related news for you</h5>
    <div class="related-news-thumbnail"></div>
    
    <h5>Can you try these news right away?</h5>
    <div class="related-news-thumbnail"></div>

    <h5>Some hot news is waiting for you!</h5>
    <div class="related-news-thumbnail"></div>

    <h5>Fresh news are here! Check it out. </h5>
    <div class="related-news-thumbnail"></div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- follow me block -->
  <div class="follow-me">
    <h3>Follow Me</h3>
    <p>Some text...</p>
  </div>
</div>
</main>

<!-- This is footer, symantec footer! :D -->
<footer>
  <h2>Footer</h2>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow! I love you dear! It's actually working now! Thanks a lot ❤❤